# Задачка по теории вероятностей

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Помогите пожалуйста с задачей: 
Известно, что МХ = -1 , DХ = 1, MУ = 1, DУ = 2. Случайные величины X и У независимы. Z = 2X – 4Y-2, тогда МZ = ? DZ = ?

Comment: Ну рука не поднимается делать за вас такое простое задание! Смотрите, например, [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B) - ну делать же нефиг!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MZ = 2*MX-4*MY-2 = -2-4-2 = -8

DZ = D(2X) + D(4Y) = 4*DX+16*DY=4*1+16*2=36
```